# Facebook rankings and kpi for specific pages

Tags: facebook, ranking, kpi

I would like to make an application or even a page in my localhost to do what [fanpage karma facebook rankings](http://www.fanpagekarma.com/Facebook-Ranking)  does.

I don't want the facebook insights because I want to have kpi,graphs/charts,rankings and/or insights for the pages i want, just like the fanpagekarma does.

Answer (score 0):

Most of this information can be obtained via

graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID which will give for example `graph.facebook.com/cocacola`

```
{
  "id": "40796308305", 
  "about": "The Coca-Cola Facebook Page is a collection of your stories showing how people from around the world have helped make Coke into what it is today.", 
  "app_id": "0", 
  "can_post": false, 
  "category": "Food/beverages", 
  "checkins": 146, 
  "cover": {
    "cover_id": "10152297032458306", 
    "source": "http://sphotos-f.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/s720x720/625442_10152297032458306_574021701_n.jpg", 
    "offset_y": 0, 
    "offset_x": 0
  }, 
  "description": "Created in 1886 in Atlanta, Georgia, by Dr. John S. Pemberton, Coca-Cola was first offered as a fountain beverage at Jacob's Pharmacy by mixing Coca-Cola syrup with carbonated water. \n\nCoca-Cola was patented in 1887, registered as a trademark in 1893 and by 1895 it was being sold in every state and territory in the United States. In 1899, The Coca-Cola Company began franchised bottling operations in the United States. \n\nCoca-Cola might owe its origins to the United States, but its popularity has made it truly universal. Today, you can find Coca-Cola in virtually every part of the world.\n\nCoca-Cola Page House Rules: http://CokeURL.com/q28a", 
  "founded": "1886", 
  "has_added_app": false, 
  "is_community_page": false, 
  "is_published": true, 
  "likes": 64355037, 
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/coca-cola", 
  "name": "Coca-Cola", 
  "talking_about_count": 1485039, 
  "username": "coca-cola", 
  "website": "http://www.coca-cola.com", 
  "were_here_count": 0
}
```

In the KPI Overview this takes care of

- Fans
- Talking about

Then when a user logins into fanpagekarma, the call to graph.facebook.com/page_id/posts can  be used to get

- Posts per day
- Response rate
- Engagement
- Post Interaction
- Post History

The rest of the detailed analytics is just some number crunching on the data from /page_id/posts

Comment: Well yeah i kinda know that stuff, but how can i call or use them inside a page running in my localhost or something like that to see the results with graphs and full analytics as the fanpage karma does?
I mean how can i use the info to show the graphs via Chart.js-master?

Comment: @Mhche you supply the data to Chart.js not really sure where you are getting at other than a full out code explanation of fanpage karma source code.

Comment: thanks for the response but i cannot really get the answer in that. What data will i supply to Chart.js? Also the source code is the easy and obvious solution. Maybe i haven't make it clear or i'm silly enough to understand. E.g. you can look here http://www.fanpagekarma.com/facebook/81221197163/Cristiano how can i get results like that? From any page that i want?